# python ONVIF Rotate Video Source on a Camera

Tags: python, onvif

I'm trying to rotate the video source for all of the ONVIF profiles by Python ONVIF. I am using Python 3.8.1 and `onvif_zeep` library:[here is the link to this library](https://pypi.org/project/onvif-zeep/)

After reading documentation on [ONVIF homepage](https://www.onvif.org/) It is not clear for me how to do this.

I use the following code:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

mycam = ONVIFCamera(Cam_ip,80,Onvif_User,Onvif_User_Pass) # the connection is done ok
media = mycam.create_media_service() # Media Service is ok

#Get The video source configurations
configurations_list = media.GetVideoSourceConfigurations() # Ok I get the Video Source configuration I wanted to select on id 0
video_source_configuration = configurations_list[0]
```

Ok now I have the Video Source stored in `video_source_configuration`. If I print it I can  get the info properly:

```
{
    'Name': 'SOURCE_VIDEO',
    'UseCount': 5,
    'SourceToken': '0',
    'Bounds': {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 0,
        'width': 1820,
        'height': 720
    },
    '_value_1': None,
    'Extension': None,
    'token': '0',
    '_attr_1': {
}
}
```

Even if I modify for instance the width or the height I can do this operation with no problems

```
video_source_configuration.width = 640
video_source_configuration.height = 420

request = media.create_type('SetVideoSourceConfiguration')

request.Configuration = video_source_configuration

request.ForcePersistence = True

media.SetVideoSourceConfiguration(request)
```

But I don't know how to modify `Video_Source_Configuration` to rotate it 90 or 270 degrees. I have read the function `media.GetVideoSourceConfigurationOptios()` and I have gotten the following response:

```
{
    'BoundsRange': {
        'XRange': {
            'Min': 0,
            'Max': 1280
        },
        'YRange': {
            'Min': 0,
            'Max': 720
        },
        'WidthRange': {
            'Min': 0,
            'Max': 1280
        },
        'HeightRange': {
            'Min': 0,
            'Max': 720
        }
    },
    'VideoSourceTokensAvailable': [
        '0'
    ],
    'Extension': {
        '_value_1': [
            <Element {http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema}Rotate at 0x243b6f4d2c0>
        ],
        'Rotate': None,
        'Extension': None
    },
    '_attr_1': None
}
```

I presume I need to modify Extension field and Rotate property, but reading the documentation I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I solved it with python 2.7 and[python-onvif](https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif) library

For selecting 'Rotate' Mode you should use the class Text from sux library.

So the following code works well and the Camera rotate all ONVIF streams properly:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera
from suds.sax.text import Text

mycam = ONVIFCamera(Cam_ip,80,Onvif_User,Onvif_User_Pass) 
media = mycam.create_media_service()

#Get The video source configurations
configurations_list = media.GetVideoSourceConfigurations() 
video_source_configuration = configurations_list[0]

request = media.create_type('SetVideoSourceConfiguration')

request.Configuration.Name = video_source_configuration.Name 
request.Configuration.UseCount = video_source_configuration.UseCount request.Configuration._token = video_source_configuration._token 
request.Configuration.Bounds = video_source_configuration.Bounds
request.Configuration.SourceTokens = video_source_configuration.SourceTokens

#Now we perform a rotation of all ONVIF streams 90 Degrees.
request.Configuration.Extension.Rotate.Mode.value=Text(u'ON')
request.Configuration.Extension.Rotate.Degree = 90

#Add persistence to store the configuration in non volatile Memory
request.ForcePersistence = True


media.SetVideoSourceConfiguration(request)
```

It works but for python 2, for python 3, I haven't found a solution at the moment.